# parseInt and negative zero in javascript: odd behavior?

Tags: javascript, zero, parseint

Why:

```
parseInt(-0, 10) // 0
parseInt('-0', 10) // -0
```

Is there a sensible reason that parseInt wouldn't do -0 for both or is this just an oddity of javascript?

Comment: What's the difference anyway?

Comment: @elclanrs: well, `5 * -0` is `-0`, and `5 * 0` is `0`.

Comment: I'm getting all positive zeroes in NodeJS. I suppose this is a browser thing.

Comment: Yeah, confirmed here as well. Node gives +0 for every combo. The browser where my test was done is Chrome for what it's worth.

Comment: I use `Node v0.11.13-pre`, I am able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`parseInt()` works on strings.  Running `parseInt()` on a number causes it to be cast to a string.

`(-0).toString()` is `0`.

Comment: Thanks, that does explain it -- but it also just moves the question over;  why should (-0).toString() return '0' and not '-0'?

Comment: @Semicolon For that question, I have no idea.  It's also odd that it's different between Node.js and Chrome since they both use V8.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to the `parseInt` is converted to a String, as per [ECMA 5.1 Spec for `parseInt`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.2),

> ```
> 1. Let inputString be ToString(string).
> ```

And [`ToString`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8.1), returns `'0'`, even if the input is `+0` or `-0`,

> ```
> 2. If m is +0 or −0, return the String "0".
> ```

That is why you are getting this behavior.

Comment: Well, that's very clear. So Chrome is correct -- but (some versions of) Node are incorrect. I'm still mystified by the rationale for ToString unsigning the -0, which unfortunately the spec doesn't provide.